# Django: Specific unique_together condition

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Article`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('author', 'title')
```

The method `get_sentinel_user`:

```
def get_sentinel_user():
    return get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]
```

Thus, using `on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user)`, I save posts after deleting the author (if he agrees to this, I ask him in a separate form). And instead of a real author, I set a "stub"-user as the author for his posts.

In such a situation, there is a problem with the uniqueness condition. If two users had articles with the same title and then one of them was deleted, then an error will occur when trying to delete the second user. Accordingly, I would like this error to be absent. So that the uniqueness condition applies only to real users and their articles. I tried this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            name='unique_combiantion_article_name_and_author',
            fields=['title', 'author'],
            condition=~models.Q(author__username='deleted')
        )
    ]
```

But then I made sure that this does not work, we cannot use `author__username`.

Right now I'm thinking about just overriding `validate_unique` method. But first I would like to ask for advice. Maybe there is some other solution for this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: One of possible solutions: additional `original_poster` field with default value = author_id and no FK. Initialize on insert, never update, include it into unique constraint instead of author. By building complex constraints take into account that a) not every database supports conditional/filtered constraints at all b) overridden method cannot be applied to database, so db won't have any constraint in this case at all. Better _keep it simple and stupid_.